# External Disk to use with TimeMachine in a AirPort Extreme

Tags: airport, time-machine

Any one know any external disk that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Again, [any usb disk should work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391/external-disk-to-use-with-itunes-in-a-airport-extreme/392#392), unless there's something I'm missing in the question.

Comment: Ok, Today I will try with the One I have