# External Disk to use with iTunes in a AirPort Extreme

Tags: itunes, airport

I have a external disk that I use now to have my iTunes collection, I want to connect the same disk to the AirPort Extreme so I dont have to use a USB port in my Notebook.

Does anyone have a reccomendation?

Answer (score 2):

Any standard USB disk should work.

Comment: Ok, Today I will try with the one I have.